# PHP Array How to match and output a different value?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array that looks like this with print_r

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 257983
            [purchase_date] => September 6, 2018
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 277846
            [purchase_date] => August 28, 2018
        )

)
```

What I want to do is match the current post (ex 277846) to the one in the array and then display the date which should be August 28, 2018. How can I do that? Could someone please point me in the right direction? I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you in advance

Comment: You can iterate the array using for/foreach, then check if the post_id matches. Then return the purchase_date of that array item. Is that what you want?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte That actually may be what I want! I'll try the foreach. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
$value = 277846;
foreach($array as $element) {
    if ($element['post_id'] == $value) {
        return $element['purchase_date'];
    }
}
```

Comment: short and easy to understand. Thank you so much. I spent hours on this and couldn't figure it out and you made it look so easy. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?:

```
$array[1]["purchase_date"]
```

I'm assuming you're trying to print position '1', field 'purchase_date' of whatever array object you're printing.

Or you can iterate through the array, and if the object.post_id == 277846, print the purcahse_date.
pseudocode:

```
for(var $x : $array) 
{ 
    if(x.post_id == 277846)
    {
        print x;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this condition 
i am taking array and i am checking condition with my_post_id

```
 $my_post_id=277846;
    $data=[['post_id'=>'257983','purchase_date'=>'September 6, 2018'],['post_id'=>'277846','purchase_date'=>'August 28, 2018']];
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
       if($my_post_id==$data[$i]['post_id']){
            echo "do something"
    } 
    }
```